# Trying to use VBOs & VAOs in JOGL (OpenGL) throws an exception wherein a buffer cannot be found

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, jogl

I am completely stuck here, so any help would be appreciated :/

I'm trying to learn how to use OpenGL 4.0 using it's Java Bindings, JOGL. It seems like now it's better to use VBO/VAOs as opposed to glBegin/End.

I'm following various sources, but for this specific aspect I used this: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle (C++)

Unfortunately, when I run my program, it throws the following exception (@ Line 41):
"`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught GLException: GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Buffer for target 0x8892 not bound on thread AWT-EventQueue-0`"

Here's my full GLEventListener implementing class (Renderer):

```java
package pRendering;

import com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL4;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

public class Renderer implements GLEventListener {

    public int vShaderProgramID;
    public int vVertShaderID;
    public int vFragShaderID;

    public int vVBO_ID;
    public IntBuffer vVBO; //uint pointer?

    public int vVAO_ID;
    public IntBuffer vVAO; //uint pointer?

    //region tmp
    float vertices[] = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };
    //endregion

    private void TriangleVBO_VAO(GL4 vGL){
        FloatBuffer vVertFloatBuffer = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(vertices);

        vGL.glGenVertexArrays(1, vVAO);
        vGL.glGenBuffers(1, vVBO);

        vGL.glBindVertexArray(vVAO_ID);

        vGL.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vVBO_ID);
        vGL.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vVertFloatBuffer.capacity() * Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT, vVertFloatBuffer, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW); // <---

        vGL.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4 /*sizeof(float)*/, 0);
        vGL.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        vGL.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        vGL.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {
        GL4 vGL = glAutoDrawable.getGL().getGL4();

        vShaderProgramID = vGL.glCreateProgram();
        try {
            vVertShaderID = Shaders.CreateShader(vGL, vShaderProgramID, GL4.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "C:\\Users\\quent\\Desktop\\def.vshd");
            vFragShaderID = Shaders.CreateShader(vGL, vShaderProgramID, GL4.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "C:\\Users\\quent\\Desktop\\def.fshd");

            Shaders.Link(vGL, vShaderProgramID);
        } catch (Exception EX) {
            EX.toString();
        }

        TriangleVBO_VAO(vGL);
    }

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {
        GL4 vGL = glAutoDrawable.getGL().getGL4();

        vGL.glClear(GL4.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL4.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        vGL.glUseProgram(vShaderProgramID);

        vGL.glBindVertexArray(vVAO_ID);

        vGL.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {
        GL4 vGL = glAutoDrawable.getGL().getGL4();

        vGL.glDetachShader( vShaderProgramID, vVertShaderID);
        vGL.glDetachShader( vShaderProgramID, vFragShaderID);
        vGL.glDeleteProgram(vShaderProgramID);
    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You should have look into our wiki, there are numerous examples, this one would have been helpful: https://jogamp.org/cgit/jogl-demos.git/tree/src/demos/es2/RawGL2ES2demo.java?id=HEAD The examples of the website you mentioned have already been ported to JOGL by another contributor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the vertex array object and the buffer object is contained in the `IntBuffer` objects `vVAO` respectively `vVBO`. You missed to assign the content of the `IntBuffer`s to the attributes `vVAO_ID` respectively `vVBO_ID`:

```java
vVAO = GLBuffers.newDirectIntBuffer(1);
vVBO = GLBuffers.newDirectIntBuffer(1);

vGL.glGenVertexArrays(1, vVAO);
vVAO_ID = vVAO.get();

vGL.glGenBuffers(1, vVBO);
vVBO_ID = vVBO.get();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I simply get a null pointer exception on the line assigning vVAO_ID :(

Comment: @BBonless You have to allocate the `IntBuffer` objects.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Your answer is correct but I advise you to use Buffers.newDirectIntBuffer() because JOGL will have to convert your indirect NIO buffers into direct NIO buffers anyway.

Comment: @gouessej Do you mean `GLBuffers.newDirectIntBuffer(1)` like [Java Code Examples for com.jogamp.opengl.util.GLBuffers#newDirectIntBuffer()](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.jogamp.opengl.util.GLBuffers&method=newDirectIntBuffer)

Comment: @Rabbit76 Something similar to this but with Int instead of Float: https://jogamp.org/cgit/jogl-demos.git/tree/src/demos/es2/RawGL2ES2demo.java?id=HEAD#n508 GLBuffers calls Buffers anyway.